# Estimating gate or transistor count for an IC

Tags: logic-gates, microchip, reliability

I'm messing around with calculating predicted failure rates using MIL-HDBK-217F.  For microcircuits (depending on linear or digital) you need to come up with a gate count or a transistor count for the piece part.  Does anyone have a rule of thumb or quick and dirty way to come up with this for some of the more complex circuits short of finding a schematic and counting?

It clearly doesn't need to be super precise given the ranges in the handbook.  For example for something like a B/P Digital Gate the ranges are 1 to 100, 101 to 1000, 1001 to 3000, etc.  So you just need to land in the ballpark.

For example, if I'm looking at a [74ALS193A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74als193a.pdf), looking at the TI datasheet it's simple enough I can count out 48 gates and some change because of the flip-flops.  All in all, for this specific case I can be confident it's less than 100.  That said I can't dig up a mfg schematic for everything.  Some piece parts only give block level or simplified diagrams...or no diagrams.  It'd be nice if I could apply some kind of axiom without reviewing the piece part schematic.  I'd thought about maybe looking at propagation delay and dividing by the typical delay for a NAND gate for that device's logic family but couldn't figure out a good way to apply that to the aforementioned binary counter.

Anyway, hope it's not a dumb question.

Comment: This kind of sounds like wanting to guess how make ingredients are used to make any particular baked good solely based on its density without using any additional information about the baked good (like type, price, purpose, flavour etc).

Comment: Yeah I figure as much.  Just wasn't sure if maybe there was a rough estimate if you at least knew the logic family combined with some kind of context from a datasheet.  I guess I'm going to just find it'll boil down to learned experience with the logic family and the parts available.  After all I know something about baking cakes and could tell you a recipe that fills two 9-inch rounds will usually need somewhere around 4-8 eggs.  I could at least tell you that you'd want to start by buying a dozen.

Comment: Ah, well if you know the function of the IC, that's a different question. One that I am, unfortunately, not knowledgeable enough to answer but I imagine could be answered from just looking at a ton of datasheets for different components that do have gate counts listed.

Comment: The failure rate does not depend on the number of transistors. It doesn't even depend on chip area. You can have the same chip function with roughly the same number of transistors from the 1970ies or today, and today the die is maybe 1/100 the size and causes less problems.

Comment: @Janka I don't disagree but gate count is part of the prediction model in MIL217.  I'm not exclusively looking at transistor or gate count.  The prediction model also requires inputs related to junction temperature depending on the device architecture, the device packaging, usage environment and quality factor among other things.

Comment: @bladpart I wouldn't be so sure about your "less than 100" statement. For CMOS (as opposed to TTL), a NAND gate will typically be 4 and an AND gate requires an inverter, so that's another 2 to make 6. And that is just one gate with two inputs. Take a look at a TTL gate for fun. (Buffered outputs will add complications.)

Comment: @jonk Sorry about the ambiguity, not sure if you're talking about number of transistors per gate.  I meant I'm confident it has less than 100 logic gates (be they AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOR, Inverter).  In MIL217 it mentions wanting a transistor count if it's a linear IC (like an LM139 or whatever), but gate count if it's a digital IC.  That all said, I'd guess the counter has somewhere around 200-300 transistors.  The handbook mentions just converting from gate count to transistors. 3 transistors per gate for TTL, and 4 for CMOS.  Guessing they're just approximating as if everything was a NAND.

Comment: @Janka You draw a conclusion that is not supported by any facts. The fact that current logic chips are smaller does not mean that they "causes less problems" even if that happens to be true.

Comment: I did not draw a conclusion. One cannot estimate the failure rate of ICs from **any** of those measures. Neither from the transistor count. From all of them as a whole, you might get an estimate.

Comment: @Janka But that's **not** what you said. You said that the failure rate "does not depend on the number of transistors" or chip area. That statement is absurd on its face.

Comment: MIL217 is a poor predictor of real failure rates and is truly horrible for really large gate count ASICs. But, in most cases it should be conservative, and if you meet your reliability goal using MIL217, you should be good. Its when you don't meet your goal that things get complicated. You can use accelerated life testing to get a better reliability estimate.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson: Sorry, English isn't my first language.